# Are medical units pertaining to blood-tests, etc. standard/universal? Or vary from country to country?

Tags: blood-tests, measurement, test-results, different-national-health, urine-test

Are medical measurements/units pertaining to blood-tests and urine-tests standardized across the globe? Or are they different?

(I thought the metric system was standard in science, but when I was talking to my French friend about a test result from a blood-test in Canada, he asked me to explain which unit it was because he was fairly sure it was different?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the measured quantities are the same across border, both names and units can vary.

The main difference is often the unit used for the concentration of each analyte : either mass per volume or mole per volume (eg: glucose 1g/L = 5.5 mmol/L), sometime variation on the unit prefix (eg: haemoglobin 120 g/L = 12 g/dL). It is of course possible to convert a value in another representation: here is a [list of normal values (PDF)](http://www.royalcollege.ca/portal/page/portal/rc/common/documents/exams/normal_values_e.pdf) in different units.

This is mostly a result of differing medical traditions/habits ([AMA style guide regarding units](http://www.amamanualofstyle.com/view/10.1093/jama/9780195176339.001.0001/med-9780195176339-div1-192#), [wikipedia on units and reference ranges](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_ranges_for_blood_tests#Units))